# select data from table related with same table

Tags: mysql

I have table items with data
items a

```
id ,  parent_id

1               
2               
3               
4       1       
5       2
```

Related with same table with data

items b

```
b_id,b_parent_id

4   , 1
```

I want to fetch result like a related b when b.id=4  and a parent_id is null

result like

```
id , b_parent_id
1        ,1
2               
3
```

Comment: please provide structure of the table

Comment: table items  fields id ,  parent_id

Comment: and what about b_id b_parent_id

Comment: thanks I get the answer by my self , please review

Answer (score 0):

I get the answer

```
select a.id,b.parent_id b_parent_id
from pages a
left join pages b
on a.id=b.parent_id and b.id=4 where a.parent_id is null ;
```